# Should I run normal flask app and sockets on the same ports?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, eventlet

I am running a module index.py as a flask app via gunicorn, eventlet and nginx.

The code is working fine but I am unable to make it run for the required time.

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ast
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import datetime
from itertools import chain
import json
import os
import operator
import sys
import time
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
CORS(app)

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/aviral/dev/bubble-process-watson')
from entity_dict import entity_dict_CRO, entity_dict_DEN, entity_dict_url_CRO, entity_dict_url_DEN

entityDict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in chain(entity_dict_url_CRO.items(), entity_dict_url_DEN.items()):
    entityDict[k].append(v)

try:
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client["Bubble"]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

start_match = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "2018-07-01 18:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

collection = "CRODEN_R16"

@app.route("/")
def helloFromBubble():
    return "Hey from Bubble!"

@app.route("/start_match")
def set_start_match():
    startToday = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    file = open("set_start_match.txt", "w")
    file.write(str(startToday))
    file.close()
    return(json.dumps(startToday, default=str))

@app.route("/list-entities")
def list_entities():
    currDict = {}
    for i in entityDict:
        names = i.split("_")
        entity_name = names[0] + names[1]
        currDict[i] = {}
        currDict[i]["name"] = entity_name
        currDict[i]["image_url"] = entityDict[i][-1]
    return(json.dumps(currDict, default=str))


@socketio.on('entities')
def entity_tweets(entity_name):
    print(entity_name)
    file = open("set_start_match.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        start_today = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            line.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(start_today)
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        diff = now - start_today
        request_match = start_match + diff
        for post in db[collection].find():
        print(post)
            if "emotion" not in post.keys():
                continue
            if post["timeStamp"] > request_match:
                if post["entity_name"] == entity_name:
                    app.logger.info("Satisfied")
                    currDict = {}
                    currDict["entity"] = post["entity_name"]
                    currDict["emotion"] = max(
                        post["emotion"].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
                    currDict["profile_image"] = post["userProfile"]
                    currDict["tweet"] = post["tweet"].encode('utf-8')
                    currDict_json = json.dumps(currDict, default=str)
                    emit('Entity_Tweet', {'data':currDict_json})
                    del currDict
                    del currDict_json
                else:
            emit('Entity_Tweet', {'data':'ignored.'})
                    #print("Ignored.")
                    #app.logger.info("Ignored")
    return "Completed."

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', debug=False)
```

This code works fine but after sometime, it just stops with a message:

> [2018-07-04 13:06:11 +0000] [3469] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT
>   (pid:3475) message handler error Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/server.py", line
>   411, in _trigger_event
>       return self.handlersevent   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line 522,
>   in _handle_eio_message
>       self._handle_event(sid, pkt.namespace, pkt.id, pkt.data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line 458,
>   in _handle_event
>       self._handle_event_internal(self, sid, data, namespace, id)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line 461,
>   in _handle_event_internal
>       r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line
>   490, in _trigger_event
>       return self.handlers[namespace]event   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_socketio/**init**.py",
>   line 251, in _handler
>       *args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_socketio/**init**.py",
>   line 634, in _handle_event
>       ret = handler(*args)   File "/home/aviral/dev/bubble-api/index.py", line 80, in entity_tweets
>       print(post)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
>   line 196, in handle_abort
>       sys.exit(1) SystemExit: 1 [2018-07-04 13:06:42 +0000] [3475] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 3475) [2018-07-04 13:06:42 +0000] [3487]
>   [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3487 [2018-07-04 13:07:55 +0000]
>   [3487] [ERROR] Socket error processing request. Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 66, in handle
>       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 56, in handle
>       self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 129, in handle_request
>       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 107, in handle_request
>       respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in
>   **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_socketio/**init**.py",
>   line 43, in **call**
>       start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line
>   47, in **call**
>       return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line
>   360, in handle_request
>       return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/server.py", line 275,
>   in handle_request
>       environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 91,
>   in handle_get_request
>       start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 133,
>   in _upgrade_websocket
>       return ws(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/async_eventlet.py",
>   line 19, in **call**
>       return super(WebSocketWSGI, self).**call**(environ, start_response)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   129, in **call**
>       self.handler(ws)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 158,
>   in _websocket_handler
>       pkt = ws.wait()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   787, in wait
>       for i in self.iterator:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   642, in _iter_frames
>       message = self._recv_frame(message=fragmented_message)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   668, in _recv_frame
>       header = recv(2)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   577, in _get_bytes
>       d = self.socket.recv(numbytes - len(data))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 363, in recv
>       return self._recv_loop(self.fd.recv, b'', bufsize, flags)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 357, in _recv_loop
>       self._read_trampoline()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 328, in _read_trampoline
>       timeout_exc=socket_timeout('timed out'))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 207, in _trampoline
>       mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/**init**.py",
>   line 163, in trampoline
>       return hub.switch()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line
>   295, in switch
>       return self.greenlet.switch() timeout: timed out [2018-07-04 13:08:58 +0000] [3487] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 66, in handle
>       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 56, in handle
>       self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 129, in handle_request
>       six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py",
>   line 107, in handle_request
>       respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in
>   **call**
>       return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_socketio/**init**.py",
>   line 43, in **call**
>       start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line
>   47, in **call**
>       return self.engineio_app.handle_request(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/socketio/server.py", line
>   360, in handle_request
>       return self.eio.handle_request(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/server.py", line 275,
>   in handle_request
>       environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 91,
>   in handle_get_request
>       start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 133,
>   in _upgrade_websocket
>       return ws(environ, start_response)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/async_eventlet.py",
>   line 19, in **call**
>       return super(WebSocketWSGI, self).**call**(environ, start_response)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   129, in **call**
>       self.handler(ws)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 158,
>   in _websocket_handler
>       pkt = ws.wait()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   787, in wait
>       for i in self.iterator:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   642, in _iter_frames
>       message = self._recv_frame(message=fragmented_message)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   668, in _recv_frame
>       header = recv(2)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/websocket.py", line
>   577, in _get_bytes
>       d = self.socket.recv(numbytes - len(data))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 363, in recv
>       return self._recv_loop(self.fd.recv, b'', bufsize, flags)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 357, in _recv_loop
>       self._read_trampoline()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 328, in _read_trampoline
>       timeout_exc=socket_timeout('timed out'))   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
>   line 207, in _trampoline
>       mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/**init**.py",
>   line 163, in trampoline
>       return hub.switch()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line
>   295, in switch
>       return self.greenlet.switch() timeout: timed out

I am running the app with:

```
gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 index:app
```

Answer (score 2):

That `while True:` is blocking the worker forever, so the worker reach it's timeout and fails. Try to avoid that kind of infinite loops inside a endpoint (Flask or SocketIO) method.

Comment: Then how should I return the newly added documents from my mongo collection? I have to emit those too.

Comment: If you need a `While True:` loop, you can put it on a thread, but not as a request answer. Try just deleting that `while True` and the `for` should work